# How can I reuse a subsearch in splunk?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Suppose I have a search: `[search index=main something]` .

I want to reuse it twice, that means to use it in the query without running the search again.

That is because I want to apply two different stats on top of the same results(by A and by A,B), calculate something and join them in the end.